# How do I sort dates by month in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

new R student here.  I am trying to sort data by month.  Here is a sample of the data I need to use, followed by the code, then my results.  Any tips for how to accomplish this?!  I'm super stuck...

[image]

[image]

This is the latest code I have been trying:

```
 library(readr)
weather <- read_csv("R/weather.csv", col_types = cols(High = col_number(), 
                                                      Low = col_number(), Precip = col_number(), 
                                                      Snow = col_number(), Snowd = col_integer()))
View(weather)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


class(weather)  #what class is dataset = dataframe
head(weather)  #structure of the dataset  

weather.month <- weather %>%   # Group data by month
  mutate(weather, 'month') %>%
  group_by(month = lubridate::floor_date(weather$Day, 'month')) %>%
  summarise(weather.month$High)
```

Then this is the errors I get:
[image]

Any help getting through this would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You have a syntax error, it should be `group_by(month = lubridate::floor_date(mdy(Day), 'month'))`

Comment: Could you please share your data as code and not as an image? Also, what format are your dates in (mdy or dmy)?

Comment: @akrun   That does it!  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be modified by converting the `Day` to `Date` class (with `mdy` or `dmy` - as it is not clear whether it is month-day-year or day-month-year format), then apply the `floor_date` by 'month' and apply the function on High column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
weather %>%   #
  group_by(month = lubridate::floor_date(mdy(Day), 'month')) %>%
  summarise(High = sum(High, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Follow up question...I'm trying to use that sorted data to create a ridgeline plot, but I'm running into errors, see below.  Any tips??

Comment: @LeAnnHall can you show the code

Comment: Not here, it's too long.  :(

Comment: @LeAnnHall can you please post as a new question. thanks

Comment: Yep, but Stack Overflow says I have to wait 90 minutes.  Then I will!

Comment: Just got the new question posted.  :)